# How to create VS Code extension that provides custom problemMatcher?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I have project that uses custom `problemMatcher`. But I would like to extract it into  an extension making it configurable. So eventually it could be used in `tasks.json` like

```json
{
    "problemMatcher": "$myCustomProblemMatcher"
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of VSCode 1.11.0 (March 2017), [extensions can contribute problem matchers via `package.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_tasks):

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "problemMatchers": [
            {
                "name": "gcc",
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Tasks can then reference it with `"problemMatcher": ["$name"]` (`$gcc` in the case of this example).

---

Instead of defining a matcher's `pattern` inline, it can also contributed in `problemPatterns` so it's reusable (for instance if you want to use it in multiple matchers):

```json
{
    "contributes": {
        "problemPatterns": [
            {
                "name": "gcc",
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        ],
        "problemMatchers": [
            {
                "name": "gcc",
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": "$gcc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```