# How to inherit tasks in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

VSCode allows developers to define [custom tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) in `.vscode/tasks.json`. How to inherit VSCode's `tasks.json`?

`tsconfig` or `tslint` could be inherited using `extends` "keyword". However I have not found such option in [tasks.json schema](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix).

My use case: I have a common library that is shared across projects. The library also define various common gulp tasks. Each project inherits `gulpfile`, `tsconfig`, `tslint` from the common library. The only problem is with `.vscode/tasks.json` especially with [custom problem matchers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher).

If the task inheritance is not *yet* possible, how to reuse custom problem matchers?

Comment: You can reuse problem matchers by defining them in an extension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705390/how-to-create-vs-code-extension-that-provides-custom-problemmatcher/41750503#41750503

Comment: @Gama11 I was considering that however devs wont be able to work on multiple projects based on different version of library. In case you open project, you will have to install particular version of that extension.